# APACHE multiple url routing

Tags: apache

thanks for clicking my question! <3.
Basically, I've tried to create a basic routing in my apache httpd installation, it looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule social/user social/profile.php
```

But if I want to create another routing to make it (for example) "social/user/sarah_thecowboy" it will open "profile.php" anyway, even if there is a rule getting a parameter. Is there a way I can do something like that?

Comment: Always put the more restrictive rule first, then the more generic one.  Also add the `[L]` tag at the end, to ensure Apache stops checking the rewrites after it finds a match.

Comment: Ohhhh okay, thanks! I will test it out!.